# angular 2 localstorage cannot find name

Tags: angular

I am using angular CLI and I am trying to use localStorage for registration component, but this is no working, it says Cannot find name 'localStorage'
This is my service

```
create(user: User) {
    return this.http.post('/signup', user, this.jwt(user)).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

  private jwt(user) {
    let currentUser = localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user);
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token });
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
  }
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: `let currentUser = localStorage.currentUser = user;`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have to add **lib:dom** in your tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

(source: [tsconfig.json](https://gist.github.com/Bloggerschmidt/06a5e59fdf1df9204b9401577572da14))

Answer (score 1):

SetItem is of type void and does not return anything

```
setItem(key: string, data: string): void;
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should be :

```
create(user: User) {
    return this.http.post('/signup', user, this.jwt(user)).map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

  private jwt(user) {
    let currentUser = user
    localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user);
    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.token });
        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    }
  }
```

---

but why exactly is this `if (currentUser && currentUser.token)` ?
if that `if` condition is critical, then you better move the localStorage.setItem('currentUser', user) line inside it.